# How to make this SVG responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I got an SVG which I have to add to a webpage in which some text was written in "Poppins" (google) font.  I assumed that SVGs just has code about which pixel to paint and of which colour.  When I added the SVG using the `<img>` tag, it didn't render correctly.

Then I read a little about it and learnt that I need to add the font inside the SVG, and use `<object>` tag to render it correctly.

I did that and now it's rendering correctly but I am unable to make it responsive like an `<img>` tag. I do not understand where shall I make the change.

SVG: https://www.opendemy.org/images/logo/test-logo.svg

```css
.container {
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

    <object data="https://www.opendemy.org/images/logo/test-logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
    </object>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

^ here, I have tried to insert the SVG in a box hoping it to take 100% of the box but it overflows.
I also tried to tweak the code of the SVG a little but nothing helps.

These SVGs are generated using MS powerpoint.

Comment: replace `width="1704" height="586"` width `viewBox="0 0 1704 586`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `width` and `height` with `viewBox="0 0 1704 586"` in source code of SVG.